# Is there a way to ignore a test completely based on a condition (if a parameter does not exist in the test)

Tags: testing

Below is my TestNG suite xml file.

```
<test name="m_AggregatorTx">
            <parameter name="logFile" value="hadoopmslogs/${Domain_Name}/${NODENAME}/Hive_961/m_AggregatorTx.log"/>
            <classes>
                    <class name="executems.main.RunMS"></class>
            </classes>
    </test>

    <test name="m_alldt">
            <parameter name="logFile" value="hadoopmslogs/${Domain_Name}/${NODENAME}/Hive_961/m_alldt.log"/>
            <parameter name="enableUT" value="true"/>
            <classes>
                    <class name="executems.main.RunMS"></class>
            </classes>
    </test>

    <test name="m_alldt_cpx">
            <parameter name="logFile" value="hadoopmslogs/${Domain_Name}/${NODENAME}/Hive_961/m_alldt_cpx.log"/>
            <classes>
                    <class name="executems.main.RunMS"></class>
            </classes>
    </test>


<test name="m_alldt_custom_query_prop">
            <parameter name="logFile" value="hadoopmslogs/${Domain_Name}/${NODENAME}/Hive_961/m_alldt_custom_query_prop.log"/>
            <parameter name="enableUT" value="true"/>
            <classes>
                    <class name="executems.main.RunMS"></class>
            </classes>
    </test>
```

In runtime, I want to ignore the tests which do not have enableUT parameter in it.
For example, in the above suite file m_AggregatorTx and m_alldt_cpx do not have enableUT parameter in them.

Note: 
1. I do not want to add enabled=true/false to my suite xml. ( Because I have 30 different suite files which have 100 test cases each)
2. Currently during runtime, I am able to Skip these tests using throw new SkipException. But once a run finishes, the results comes as this:

===============================================
Hive_961

## Total tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Skips: 2

3. I do not want the two cases to show up in the Skips section in the result. I want those cases to be ignored during run-time.
   I want the result something like this:

===============================================
Hive_961

## Total tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Skips: 0

```
if(enableBugB.equals("true"))
            {
                    System.out.println("enableBugB is set to true in this Test Case");
                    boolean result = Services.runMapping(applicationName, mappingName, database, runID);
                    if(runID != null && !runID.isEmpty())
                    {

                        VerifyMapping.compareResults(verifyXml, runID, logPath,result);
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        VerifyMapping.compareResults(verifyXml, mappingName, logPath,result);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //System.out.println("enableBugB is not present for this Test. Hence skipping this Test Case..");
                    throw new SkipException("enableBugB is not enabled. Skipping this Test Case..");

                }
```

Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Do not use Urgent in title when posting questions. also try to avoid including tags in the title.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.
You will need to access test context.

Basically in `testng.xml`:

```
<suite name="Parameter Checker">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="listeners.ParametrizedMethodInterceptor" />
    </listeners>

    <test name="Without Parameter">
        <classes>
            <class name="TestClass" />
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test name="With Parameter">
        <parameter name="Name of the Parameter" value="Value of the Parameter" />
        <classes>
            <class name="TestClass" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

And then any listener that can catch the value of this parameter and runs before test. I have tried to do it with `IAnnotationTransformer` with reflection, but access to the value of parameter was not possible without method instantiation and there is no test context.

With `IMethodInterceptor`, however, it was simple:

```
public class ParametrizedMethodInterceptor implements IMethodInterceptor {

    @Override
    public List<IMethodInstance> intercept(List<IMethodInstance> list,
                                           ITestContext iTestContext) {
        String parameterValue = iTestContext
                .getCurrentXmlTest()
                .getParameter("Name of the Parameter");
        return (parameterValue != null)? list : new LinkedList<>();
    }
}
```

Those intercepted methods have no dependents and do not depend on any other test methods.

Test class:

```
public class TestClass {

    @Test
    @Parameters("Name of the Parameter")
    public void testMethod(@Optional("unset") String parameter) {
        System.out.print("In testMethod. ");
        System.out.println("Parameter: " + parameter + ".");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
In testMethod. Parameter: Value of the Parameter.

Test ignored.
```

For the report generation try using two listeners:

```
<listeners>
    <listener class-name="listeners.ParametrizedMethodInterceptor" />
    <listener class-name="listeners.ParametrizedReportListener" />
</listeners>
```

and skip processing of test results without parameter:

```
public class ParametrizedReportListener implements IReporter {

    @Override
    public void generateReport(List<XmlSuite> xmlSuites,
                               List<ISuite> suites,
                               String outputDirectory) {
        for(ISuite suite : suites) {
            suite.getResults().values().stream()
                    .filter(result -> result
                            .getTestContext()
                            .getCurrentXmlTest()
                            .getParameter("Name of the Parameter") != null)
                    .forEach(result -> {
                        System.out.println("Parameter found!");
                        System.out.println("Output formatting here.");
                    });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Grzegorz. This solution indeed solved all the problems and save lot of my time.

Comment: Sorry, I am hitting with one issue now, the emailable-report.html that gets generated at the end is having the entries for the Ignored tests as well:

Comment: As you see below, the result numbers are correct. But the tests that have been ignored still show up in the emailable-report
Test Methods

Passed Scenarios

Passed # skipped # failed Total

m_RS_RS_Public 0 0 0 1 72.8 seconds  

m_RS_FF_QAtest 0 0 0 0 0.0 seconds  

m_RS_FF_Adpqa 0 0 0 0 0.0 seconds  

m_RS_RS_QAtest 0 0 0 0 0.0 seconds  

m_RS_RS_Adpqa 0 0 0 1 89.4 seconds  

m_RS_FF_Public 0 0 0 0 0.0 seconds  

Total 0 0 0 2 162.3 seconds

Comment: What are you using for generation of this report? Any kind of listener?

Comment: No. I am not using a specific listener. The default IReporter is being used.

Comment: Should I implement the IReporter and override generateReport method? If so, could you please give an example. Also please suggest if this can be achieved in any other easy way.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that. The standard output result on test execution considers only the tests that have the parameter enabled. But the emailable-report.html file still has entries of cases which are ignored.  Won't your solution ignore adding  to emailable-report.html the cases which have not run?

Comment: It is a partial solution. I have filtered the tests, where this parameter is set, the rest is your task.

Comment: Another idea would be to write some HTML postprocessing code.